# How to allow child element to scroll when content increases dynamically if its parent is positioned fixed?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a parent `div` which is `position:fixed`. I have `ul` `li` as its child elements. The content of `li` comes from ajax dynamically. When there is few content (fewer number of lists) then no problem and user can see and read all list easily without need to scroll. But when there are a plenty of lists comes from database then user can not even see bottom lists which are not in viewport range. So I want in this case user can scroll lists to see bottome content too which is currently hidden because of its parent's fixed position.

**Update:**

I have made a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sachinsharma1507/25aechrq/)

Ok overflow:scroll or auto solves my problem. But I am having another issue to in spite of this solution. I have a sticky footer nav bar just below the `ul` `li`. This hides the last `li` item. I want list items to scroll until the last item displays otherwise it remains behind the sticky footer nav bar.

Comment: Can you share your code

Comment: It's funny, the last line `So how can we do it. Please give a jsfiddle for demo.`

Comment: use overflow: auto on your div

Answer (score 0):

As I can't see your code I'm just able to do a suggestion.

If your div or ul, eventually, has fixed height, a `div, ul{overflow:scroll}` could solve your problem.

I would give you a more refined answer if you post your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `overflow: auto` property. On fixed position elements, this will specify that you should hide the overflow but allow scrolling.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/we8agah4/

Answer (score 0):

It solves your problem. Try `overflow:scroll;`

```
.mobile_tool
{
    border:1px solid red;
    height:100%;
    overflow:scroll;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width:300px;
}
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/25aechrq/1/)

PS: Welcome to Stackoverflow! In order to don't have your questions downvoted, always, try to be as specific as possible.

**UPDATE:**

> Ok overflow:scroll or auto solves my problem. But I am having another issue to in spite of this solution. I have a sticky footer nav bar just below the ul li. This hides the last li item. I want list items to scroll until the last item displays otherwise it remains behind the sticky footer nav bar.

To solve this problem you need to make `footer{position:fixed}` or remove the `position: fixed` from `.mobile_tool`, as long as the `position:fixed` alters the "natural" flow of layout

Comment: but by removing footer fixed position, it screws up my design.

Comment: I'd say you need to make your foot fixed, if want yo use the `.mobile_tool` fixed. Always you change the position property you are requesting the change in the natural flow of layout.

Comment: You need to choose: the both with fixed position, or with nothing (default position).

Take a look on this [guide](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)